# Is there a way to remesh an object to match the shading?

Tags: mesh, shaders

How do I remesh a model to match, as closely as possible, the curves from the smooth shaper, while retaining the sharp edge settings?

[image]

Comment: You are probably wanting to use the subdivision surface modifier with creases, it has many quirks though, you will need to learn how it works. Follow this, it's from an older version of Blender but it has everything you will need. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yi87Dap_WOc&t=442s

Answer (score 1):

I figured out a solution.

By marking the 'Sharp' edges as 'Ceases', and then using the 'Subdivision Surface' modifier (which lets you acknowledge creases). This seems to smooth everything out really well, without the need for shaders.

1. Tab into edit mode, and select the edges that you want to preserve, right click and mark as creases (or Shift-E and drag)
2. Tab out of edit mode, and select the Subdivision modifier
   2a. Toggle 'Use Creases'
   2b. Step the 'Viewport' (or whatever's relevant) setting up until you meet the desired smoothness
3. Apply